# Using SELECT CASE and SUM: MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I can't figure out how to `SUM` up and down votes on a certain item while also returning whether or not a given user voted on this item.

Here's my Votes table:

```
item_id vote voter_id
1        -1     joe
1         1     bob
1         1     tom
3         1     bob
```

For `item_id=1` here's the data I want to show:

If `Joe` is looking at the page:

```
total up votes: 2
total down votes: 1
my_vote: -1
```

`Bob`:

```
total up votes: 2
total down votes: 1
my_vote: 1
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN voter_id = 'joe' and vote=1 THEN 1 
WHEN voter_id = 'joe' and vote='-1' THEN -1
ELSE 0 END)
AS my_vote, item_id, sum(vote=1) yes, sum(vote='-1') no
FROM Votes
WHERE item_id=1
```

The issue is that `my_vote=0` if I use the `MAX` function and `vote=-1` (Joe's scenario). Similarly, `my_vote=0` if I use the MIN function and the `vote=1` (Bob's scenario).

Thoughts?

Comment: How do you get `total up votes: 2` when there's 3 votes in the table that are `+1`?

Comment: @MarcB there are 2 items and so only 2 up votes on `item_id=1`

Comment: Why do you have `vote=1` and `vote='-1'`.  Is your data a string or a numeric?  Try sticking to just one data-type in your expressions...

Comment: @MatBailie how to account for up vote, down vote, and not voting? I'm using a `TINYINT` which hasn't triggered an error in matching strings or INTs. What should I do instead? This particular data-type issue has been in the back of my mind for awhile...

Comment: int/tinyint/mediumint/bigint will all auto-convert between each other, subject to truncation/data loss if you try to stuff a (say) 32bit value into an 8bit field

Comment: @MarcB the only values i'll knowingly INSERT/UPDATE into this field are `-1`, `1`, and `0`. Is that ok?

Comment: yep, that's fine. tinyint is an 8bit field type, and has a range of 0-255 (unsigned) and -128 to +127 (signed)

Comment: @MarcB thanks great now i know

Comment: technically, if you're hideously tight on space, you could use a simple bit field. 0 = downvote, 1 = upvote, null = no vote. But that opens various flavors of canned worms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN voter_id = 'Joe' THEN vote ELSE NULL END)   AS my_vote,
  sum(vote= 1)   AS yes_votes,
  sum(vote=-1)   AS no_votes
FROM
  Votes
WHERE
  item_id = 1
GROUP BY
  item_id
```

Or, possibly more flexible...

```
SELECT
  Votes.item_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Users.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN Votes.vote ELSE NULL END)   AS my_vote,
  sum(Votes.vote= 1)   AS yes_votes,
  sum(Votes.vote=-1)   AS no_votes
FROM
  Votes
LEFT JOIN
  Users
    ON  Users.user_id = Votes.voter_id
    AND Users.user_id = 'Joe'
WHERE
  Votes.item_id = 1
GROUP BY
  Votes.item_id
```

Comment: For those coming across this answer, the first code block doesn't appear to be correct but the 2nd one definitely is. Also the answer by @491243 works too, its just MatBailie was more thorough.

Comment: @timpeterson - In what way doesn't the first code block work?   http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6064/4

Comment: your first code block and sqlfiddle do work but I'm having trouble seeing why it is different from the code I wrote. They look the same to me that's why I said I didn't think it was correct. Thoughts?

Comment: @timpeterson - I used NULL and you used 0.  NULL is never the result of MIN or MAX unless all values are NULL or there are no values at all.

Comment: oh wow, that was a trivial mistake on my part, that was bugging me forever, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subquery to get the user vote and assuming that the user can only vote once per `item_id`.

```
SELECT  SUM(vote = 1) totalUpVotes,
        SUM(vote = -1) totalDownVotes,
        (SELECT MAX(vote) 
        FROM votes b
        WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id AND
                b.voter_id = 'joe') my_vote
FROM    votes a
WHERE   item_id = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6064/1)

Comment: @MatBailie why is a subquery worse than a `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

My answer's pretty much the same, but for those of us who love stored procs I've cleaned it up a little:

```
declare p_item_id int;
declare p_voter_id varchar(10);

select 
    sum(vote = 1) as TotalUpVotes
    , sum(vote = -1) as TotalDownVotes
    , sum(vote) as TotalScore
    , sum(case when p_voter_id = voter_id then vote else 0 end) as my_vote
from Votes v
where p_item_id = v.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

select 'total up votes' as descr, count(*) as num
from Votes
where item_id=1 and vote=1
union all
select 'total down votes', count(*)
from Votes
where item_id=1 and vote=-1
union all
select 'my_vote' as descr, vote
from Votes
where item_id=1 and voter_id = 'joe'